# aparapi OpenCLDevice.best() returned null

Tags: opencl, aparapi

i am trying to play with aparapi but i haven't even started. Tried to go from https://vasanthexperiments.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/aparapi-java-matrix-multiplication-example/#comments this code, but right after execution i get:"

feb 02, 2016 8:12:30 PM com.amd.aparapi.KernelRunner warnFallBackAndExecute
WARNING: Reverting to Java Thread Pool (JTP) for class AparapiMatMul: GPU request can't be honored OpenCLDevice.best() returned null

What are the troubleshooting steps, had really no luck googling. I have newest catalyst and amd sdk installed, my cars is radeon hd 6950.

Comment: opencl 2 should be in new ati catalyst driver, when i check catalyst, under software tab, there is only opengl, might that be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

There is a sample in the aparapi examples project that lists all devices in your environment:

https://github.com/Syncleus/aparapi-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/com/aparapi/examples/info